# In scalatest, how to show full diff in test result?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

When there is an equality assertion in scalatest that fails. It generally shows only the different part, e.g.:

```
"...error;
!I e: F[Arg]
[g invalid because
nonconformant bounds;
[Arg, Nothing]
[A <: __wrapper$1$47213a912399466a973eddce7b3420f4.__wrapper$1$47213a912399466a973eddce7b3420f4.]Bounds.Base, B]
  im..." did not equal "...error;
!I e: F[Arg]
[Bounds.g invalid because
nonconformant bounds;
[Arg, Nothing]
[A <: ]Bounds.Base, B]
  im..."
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: "...error;
!I e: F[Arg]
[g invalid because
nonconformant bounds;
[Arg, Nothing]
[A <: __wrapper$1$47213a912399466a973eddce7b3420f4.__wrapper$1$47213a912399466a973eddce7b3420f4.]Bounds.Base, B]
  im..." did not equal "...error;
!I e: F[Arg]
[Bounds.g invalid because
nonconformant bounds;
[Arg, Nothing]
[A <: ]Bounds.Base, B]
  im..."
```

A lot of information are lost in this report. In addition, When the IDE is armed with a diff parser, it will show the comparison result incorrectly. Is there way to disable this feature in scalatest, so there won't be any ellipsis in the report?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is impossible at the moment starting with ScalaTest 3.x.x without writing your own custom assertion code. See [this issue](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1232).

You can change the *prettifier* to `Prettifier.basic` like this for example:

```scala
import scalatest.org.Assertions._
import org.scalactic.Prettifier

assert(foo == bar)(Prettifier.basic, org.scalactic.source.Position.here)
```

But even then I it will use the `StringDiffer` [with a hard coded `MaxContext` of 20 characters.](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/main/jvm/scalactic/src/main/scala/org/scalactic/Differ.scala#L93)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the flag `-- -Dtest.show_diff=true`. The full command will look like: `test-only *TestFileName* -- -Dtest.show_diff=true`

Comment: Presumably this answer is about sbt command line, but I can't even get that to work. How would one turn this option on in say IntelliJ?

Comment: I don't think this works with ScalaTest 3.x.x anymore. I can't find the string show_diff in the source code. See my other answer.